# Adding jQuery touch events to website for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile

My team is going to be building a lightweight website for use on mobile devices using mobile Webkit.  Our current website uses jQuery.

I took a look at jQuery Mobile and jQTouch frameworks, and they are geared towards mobile web apps.  We don't need all that extra overhead.  Essentially, we want to add simple touch events using jQuery.  Is there anything lighter than jQuery Mobile or jQTouch, or do we have to roll our own code?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://hankchizljaw.co.uk/tutorials/make-your-mouse-events-touch-friendly-with-jquery-tutorial/28/04/2012/) approach which variates your binds depending on what device your users are using

Comment: Dead link and no code examples. This is why links are poor answers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery touchwipe plugin which is very light weight.

http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library

Answer (score 1):

Starting from jQuery Mobile 1.2 you can build use their mobile download builder at http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

This tool can package only the features you actually need and that can for example include only virtual mouse events and touch events and nothing else.